# Main Lug Load Center

Tags: electrical

Can I install a 225 amp main lug load center "downstream" from my 100 amp external cutoff?  I run all gas appliances, I'm looking into gas air conditioning as well...  I only want the big panel for the sake of not having a crowded box, and more available circuits than currently allowed in my old 20 space panel.

Elroy

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. I'm no pro, but my guess it would be fine. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Is the 100a thing a meter+panel combination, or only a meter+shutoff with a 100A panel that you're replacing?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  That is exactly what we recommend.

You can go as large as 42 space for just a few dollars more.  Beyond 42 space, the cost gets prohibitive.

There is no problem having the subpanel be of a larger ampacity than the breaker protecting it.

Comment: Agreed, but do label the incoming supply ie 100A or 150A so people know...

Comment: @SolarMike this shouldn't be that unusual. People ought to be checking service size before provisioning anything big enough to justify recalculating.  Available 100A-bus panels don't provide enough breakers for a modern gas house with 100A service, so it almost has to be done.